# How to echo php array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have array

```
array(2) {
  ["Smiley TV"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Speed"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["download"]=>
      string(4) "9510"
      ["upload"]=>
      string(5) "33775"
    }
    ["Turbo"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["download"]=>
      string(4) "2427"
      ["upload"]=>
      string(5) "19696"
    }
  }
  ["Victory Media"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Speed"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["download"]=>
      string(4) "4144"
      ["upload"]=>
      string(5) "80445"
    }
  }
}
```

How i can echo this array in the table

[image]

I this array i have name of partners( smiley tv/ victory media) and traffic(Speed/turbo) and download/upload values, how can i represent this data to the this table, with using foreach(because pertners and traffic can be more than two). So i need represent all partners at the head of this table 
traffic at the left and speed is under the partners.

Comment: What is the question here? You yourself suggest to use a `foreach` loop. So go and implement what you are looking for.

Comment: Tip: You can create the thead and tbody of an table at the same time and combine these at the end. So if you know how foreach works and if you know how to make a table. it will be easy.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need assistance in building the HTML table only since you already know `foreach` in PHP? If not, then are you looking for complete solution?